# Allow iframe scroll in x-axe for smaller screens with iframe-resizer

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using iframe-resizer to adjust the height of my iframe to its content's height. So far is working great, I have only one issue with the witdh. When loaded, it takes the screen width to set the iframe, that's ok for desktop size screen but for mobile I'd like to allow scrolling on the x-axe. Any suggestions?

Here's my iframeresize initialization:

```
if (document.getElementById('iframe')){
        $('iframe').iFrameResize({
            autoResize: true,
            scrolling: false,
            maxWidth: screen.width,
            sizeWidth: true,
            //widthCalculationMethod: 'taggedElement',
            checkOrigin: [reports_server],
            //log: true
        });
    }
```

and here's my css:

```
.iframe-content{
/*  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 640px;*/
  width: -moz-available;
  width: 100% !important;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

@media (max-width : 768px) {
  .iframe-content{
      overflow-x: scroll !important;
  }
}
```

and the html part for the iframe:

```
<iframe title="myiframe" id="iframe" class="iframe-content" src="mysource" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a minwidth in iframe-resizer.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#minheight--minwidth

Comment: Yep, that worked! The only thing I don't like about it is that the width won't be dynamic (set to the content's width). Is there a way to send a message from the iFrame's content to the container page with the width?

Comment: Their are options to do that, look at `sizeWidth` in the docs.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code I'm getting no luck with with showing x-scroll bars